# dateFromString not covering valid date

Tags: mongodb, date, aggregation

I am trying to covert a date in Mongo. We are not yet on 4.0 so I have to use dateFromString.

My date is stored is a valid date: "2019-02-05T03:38:52.441Z"

I can do this on my local 4.0.6 and this works great!

```
{ $toDate: "$eventTime" }
```

but I need to run this on an older version of Mongo.. and I changed to this:

```
{ $dateFromString: { dateString:  "$eventTime" }}
```

I get the following error:

```
"$dateFromString requires that 'dateString' be a string, found: date with value 2019-02-05T03:38:52.441Z"
```

Looks like a valid date to me... any ideas? Other than upgrading Mongo :)

Comment: [Working](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tw-IDKzd4na)

Comment: drat..not sure what is going on then..  (btw that is a cool playground I was not aware of it.. !). Thanks for testing this.

Comment: @Raphael I tried to reproduce this. And it looks like eventTime is already a date not string. You can supply date time into $toDate and it will return the same date, but it doesn't work with $dateFromString where string is required.

Comment: Doh!.. in fact you are correct my test data config was created from an output and I did not have ISODate on the dates.. my bad. Thank you all for the pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add this to my test data:
var ISODate = require('isodate');

ISODate("2019-08-13T17:54:00.800Z"),